# Middleware doesn't work as expected - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I want to make a middleware to protect admin routes in laravel 5.2 app.
user_type isn't a field in users table in my db, but in a separate table :
 [image]

Admin's user_type_id is 4 
I made this middleware :

```
class AdminMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $authedUserID = Auth::id();

        $user = User::query()
                ->leftjoin('users_user_types as uut', 'uut.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('uut.user_id',"=","$authedUserID")
                ->get(['users.*',
                        'uut.user_type_id as userType'])->first();

        if ($user['userType'] !=4)
        {

            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and put this in $routeMiddleware array in kernel.php :

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
```

and this is one of admin routes I want to apply my middleware on :

```
Route::get('ptyadmin', 'AdminController@show')->middleware('admin');
```

**The Problem** is that when I go to this route with admin user(user_type = 4) or normal user(user_type = 1) it redirects to /home in both cases !!

**Why does this happen and how can I fix it ??**

Comment: Where is your `auth` middlewar in route?

Comment: I put it inside AdminController : 
public function __construct(User $user, JWTAuth $jwtauth)
   {
      $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => [

           ]]);
       
   }  @mrabbani

Comment: Dump  `dd(Auth::id())` in `AdminMiddleware` and check the value?

Comment: Thanks @mrabbani it works when I put jwt.auth middleware in routes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I put jwt.auth middleware in routes.php :

```
Route::get('ptyadmin', 'AdminController@show')
->middleware('jwt.auth')
->middleware('admin');
```

instead of putting it in AdminController :

```
public function __construct(User $user, JWTAuth $jwtauth)
```

{

```
   $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => []]);
```

}

Comment: But why does this happen ??  is it because when I put it in AdminController the admin middleware is applied first ? @mrabbani

Answer (score 1):

`first` method returns object

```
if ($user->userType !=4)
```

Also use `select`instead `get`

```
->select(['users.*','uut.user_type_id as userType'])->first();
```

Comment: Yes I tried to use it as an object, but it was returning an error  because the user wasn't authenticated before I found the answer to fix it. But now this is working , thanks.

Comment: Why do you suggest using select() instead of get() ?? @Niklesh

Comment: Get is to get result, and select is for custom columns : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects ,